# "Edit Top 200 Rows" not working for SQL Server 16.0 - Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-18, sql-server-2022

I am trying to "Edit top 200 rows" in SQL Server Express edition, but it's returning with the blank file as shown here:

[Showing blank file with disable tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvpH7.png)

I have installed this SQL Server on premise. I can select the data and update the data with query, but I'm not able to use the "Edit top 200 rows" feature.

Am I missing some permissions or its not available due to this SQL Server version which include Azure?

I have re-installed SSMS and restarted machine but it doesn't work. I have checked the permissions which are sysadmin. It should work so I can update data directly in the rows.

Comment: To repeat what I've said to the last 2 people I've seen ask this question (in as many days): 1. Don't use the "Edit top 200 rows" _'feature'_, it's buggy and quirky. 1b. Use a `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` statements instead. 2. What version of SSMS are you using?"

Comment: I am using SSMS v18.10. 
I can use the queries but "Edit top 200 rows" is easy for quick insert/update/delete and haven't found any problem regarding it so far.

Comment: SSMS 18.10 has *no* support for SQL Server 2022. Minimal support for it was added in 18.12, however, if you are using SQL Server 2022 you should be using SSMS 19, which has *full* support for SQL Server 2022. Of course, this doesn't change my point on the "Edit top 200 rows" *feature*; steer clear of it and use T-SQL instead.

Comment: But SSMS 19 is actually not yet finished... Beta version only !

Comment: SSMS is now released, and seems fine for using "Edit top 200 rows" feature.  It is really useful when you want to edit say a mapping table where you want to manually review the map say between suppliers or other unstructured/messy data.

Answer (score 37):

SSMS 19.0 resolved my issue. SSMS 18.10 has no support for SQL Server 2022.

Answer (score 8):

Installing SSMS 19 resolved the issue for me too.

Available at this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19?

A point to note, I could not locate the version 19 immediately using type-ahead. But it can be located clicking the start button and scrolling down.

[image: startmenu]

Answer (score 5):

SSMS 18 will not work correctly for SQL 2022 databases.  Use SSMS 19 for SQL 2022 databases.

While certain aspects work with version 18, some simple operations like right clicking a table and selecting "Edit Top 200 Rows" will return just a blank tab with no errors or notices.

[image: Edit Top 200 Rows]

Answer (score 2):

server management studio 19 solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

SSMS 19 resolves the problem, but I think it important to echo what Pete said. When you install SSMS19 it installs like an update, but actually installs alongside SSMS18 so you need to make sure you are using right shortcuts etc.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue happens for me, just all of a sudden for **SSMS 19.0 Preview 3**.

Installing [SSMS 19.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16) fixed the issue.
*Note: you have to completely uninstall the previous version.*

---

Alternatively, if you use Visual Studio (in my case, it's the 2022 version), you can go to View ⇝ Server Explorer ⇝ connect to your database ⇝ right-click on the table you want ⇝ Show Table Data.

This will also allow you to edit it and, by the way, without 200 rows restriction:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that this can also be done in VS. The 200 rows is not really a restriction in SSMS. It is more like a default, you can edit this TOP(200) when you go to the SQL pane (CTRL+3).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Then I realize that When  UPDATE or DELETE queries with BEGIN TRANSACTION, this issue occurred. Because of I forgot to COMMIT TRANSACTION after UPDATE or DELETE queries.

So I apply to COMMIT TRANSACTION, my issue is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Did you recently install multiple .NET Framework applications and MS software? If so, you might need to reset your network adapter.

Try running the following command in CMD (Run as Administrator):

> netsh winsock reset

Comment: I have no idea how this is even supposed to be related to the asked question. The question has *nothing* to do with networking.