# SQL Server tables not showing up

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with tables. When I want to view my tables in Microsoft SQL Server ("Edit 200 Rows" function), I get a white screen. It appears when I want to view my table with query.

System:

[image: System]

White screen:

[image: White Screen]

Query screen:

[image: Query]

I wanted to view my database any see it from "Edit 200 Rows" section

Comment: your table has one record only and it has been displayed already

Comment: See ["Edit Top 200 Rows" not working for SQL Server 16.0 - Express Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74613517/719186)

Comment: _SSMS version 19.0 Preview 3 is now available and is the recommended version of SSMS for SQL Server 2022 (16.x). [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19)._ Ref: [What's new in SQL Server 2022 (16.x)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16)